# How do I correctly set up an unread message indicator for a chat app using Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I've built a chat feature into my app using the `JSQMessagesViewController` library and `Firebase`. There is a tableView of conversations that include labels for the username and `lastMessage` received from that user. Currently, I am displaying a small dot and changing the `lastMessage` label's font to bold when there is an unread message in the conversation. I've implemented a method for indicating unread messages, but I know the method is incorrect:

When a message is sent by User A, a direct child of the conversation called  `readMessage` is updated in Firebase with the value `NO`. Then when User B selects the conversation row I'm using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to update `readMessage` to `YES`. This is causing obvious problems though because if User A sends a message, the conversation shows up unread for both users, not just User B.

How do I properly accomplish this so that new messages are only shown as unread to the user receiving the message?